Difficulty Connecting to Supabase S3-Compatible Storage
I am trying to connect to Supabase's S3-compatible storage but am encountering some difficulties. The Supabase endpoint I am working with is structured as follows:
https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.supabase.co/storage/v1/s3
Could you provide guidance or examples on how to establish a connection to this endpoint? Any help or documentation links would be greatly appreciated.
InvalidEndpointError: Invalid endPoint : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.supabase.co/storage/v1/s3
    at new TypedClient (file:///home/node/.cache/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/minio/8.0.2/dist/esm/internal/client.mjs:58:13)
    at new Client (file:///home/node/.cache/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/minio/8.0.2/dist/esm/minio.mjs:32:8)

}

    this.client = new Client({
      endPoint: S3_ENDPOINT,
      port: S3_PORT,
      useSSL: S3_SSL,
      region: S3_REGION,
      accessKey: S3_ACCESS_KEY,
      secretKey: S3_SECRET_KEY,
      pathStyle: true,
    });


also open an issue on minio js repo
https://github.com/minio/minio-js/issues/1370
